# $f(x) \mid g(x) \iff g(x) \in \langle f(x) \rangle$. Isn't this trivial?

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory

> Let $F$ be a field and $f(x), g(x) \in F[x]$. Show that $f(x)$ divides $g(x)$ if and only if $g(x) \in \langle f(x) \rangle$.

This seems... almost trivial to me (which is usually a sign that I'm missing something):

We first assume that $f(x) \neq 0$ because zero divides everything, and $\langle 0 \rangle = \{0\}$.

If $g(x) \in \langle f(x) \rangle$, then $f(x)~|~g(x)$ by the definition of a principal ideal (that is, if $g(x)$ is in the ideal generated by $f(x)$, it's just a multiple of $f(x)$).

If $f(x)~|~g(x)$, then $g(x) = q(x)f(x)$ for $q(x) \in F[x]$. But $q(x)f(x) \in \langle f(x) \rangle$, so $g(x) \in \langle f(x) \rangle$.

As often (**often**) happens, a problem that seems so simple usually means I'm missing something—especially when I made no use of the fact that $F$ is a field. Am I going wrong with a definition, or...

Comment: I don't think you are missing anything. This is really trivial.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen In that case, what a strange homework problem. Thanks for the answer, though.

Comment: It is really trivial...but important, and most probably you were expected to do what you **did** ...

Answer (score 1):

As has been pointed out, this exercise is as easy as you thought. In particular, your argument is complete. The only mistake is when you said "zero divides everything"; I believe you meant everything (other than the zero) divides zero.

Comment: I believe zero divides zero as well.

Comment: I don't think so. If $R$ is a Euclidean domain, and $a, b \in R$, $b \neq 0$, then there are unique $q, r \in R$ such that $a = bq + r$; if $r = 0$, we say $b$ divides $a$. You could try to extend the definition to the $b = 0$ and while it is true that $0 = 0q + 0$, $q$ is no longer unique.

Comment: From what I know, definition of "$a$ divides $b$" is "there is $c$ such that $b=ac$", by which it's clear that $0$ divides itself. Of course if you provide a different definition of divisibility, the answer might change.

Comment: I've always seen that definition omit the case $a = 0$ (using your letters), but as you say, definitions can vary.